# How to convert string array property to string to save in the sql server as comma seperated row mongo db to sql server C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, mongodb, entity-framework

I have a collection in mongo db "computers",I want to retrieve the collect and save it into sql server using Entity framework. The problem is that the collection have an array object.I want to convert it to string and save. please help, Thank you. SQL server skips the string [] credentials and inserts rest.

**Mongo db collection**

```
{
"_id": ObjectId('57852fcsdsdsdsd2662a0ce400'),
"machineName": "AAADESKTOP",
"updated": ISODate('2017-05-17T15:09:39.399Z'),
"__v": 111,
"credentials": [
    "####################",
    "####################",
    "#################",
    "#####################"
],
"clientVersion": "2.12.2",
"lastActivity": ISODate('2017-05-17T16:30:50.165Z'),
"secret": "####################"
```

}

```
**C# code**


    var client = new MongoClient();

    var db = client.GetDatabase("Computerdata");
    var collection = db.GetCollection<Computers>("computers");

    var data = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToListAsync().Result;

    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        EntityFramewrokContext.Computers.Add(item);
        EntityFramewrokContext.SaveChanges();

    }




    public class Computers
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string machineName { get; set; }
    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Representation = BsonType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime updated { get; set; }
    public int version { get; set; }
    public string[] credentials { get; set; } 
    public string clientVersion { get; set; }
    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Representation = BsonType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime lastActivity { get; set; }
    public string secretKey { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Not sure what you need help with here. But don't store delimited data like that. It violates 1NF and causes untold amounts of anguish.

Comment: Please read about Database Normalization https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: entity framework skips "string[] credentials " the following is not saved                        "credentials": [
    "####################",
    "####################",

    "#####################"
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a table called `Computer` in SQL Server (That you want to write these records to), then you should also create a table called `ComputerCredential` that has the following columns:

```
CredentialId  int
ComputerId    int
Credential    nvarchar(200)
```

Then for each credential in the array you should create a `ComputerCredential` entity.

If you desperately want to do it the way you asked.  Then:

```
var creds = String.Join(",", computer.credentials);
```

That will take the array of credentials and make them into a single comma separated string.

When you retrieve the values you can do this:

```
var creds = commaSepCredentials.Split(',');
```

To retrieve the array.  But don't do this, do the first option and learn about relations and joins in SQL Server.  It's the power in relational databases.

Comment: Thanks louthster.I am trying to retrieve data from mongo db collection and insert into SQL using entity framework. I cant figure out solution.  if  i use var creds = String.Join(",", computer.credentials);, where would I insert this statement?

Comment: since SQL server uses flat tables, you should introduce the attribute creds in your object and model, not map credentials and fill creds/credentials before saving/after retrieving data from database. Another solution is to introduce new credential objects for the one-to-many-relationship in order to be mapped to two tables and joint automatically.